# Context.ExecuteQueryAsync not trigerring

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, jquery-ajax

I am debugging the code below and the line Context.ExecuteQueryAsync is not being trigerred. I am not getting any error.

```
async function updateListItem(listName, itemId, itemProperties, pageurl, context, listItem) {
try {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + itemId + ")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": '*'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (M_DEBUG) {
                console.log("department added");
            }
            console.log('department added');
            // publish the news
            listItem.get_file().publish("Publishing");
            console.log(context);

            try{
            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    if (M_DEBUG) {
                        console.log("file published");
                    }
                    console.log(pageurl);
                    // redirect to news page in edit mode
                    window.location.replace(pageurl + "?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design");
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    if (M_DEBUG) {
                        console.log("error while publishing file:" + args.get_message() +
                            '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                    }
                }
            );}

            catch(err){
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            if (M_DEBUG) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the item(file) is checked out before updating.

You can print the error details using error handler as demonstrated below:

```
$.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+itemId+")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            //...
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
});
```

Try the following script to update and publish the item:

```
Update();
function Update() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        var listName = "Pages";   
        var itemId = 1; // Update Item Id here
        var titleVal = "test";
        var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
        var itemProperties = {
            "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
            "Title": titleVal    
        };
        var pageurl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Sites/<site>/Pages/p1.aspx";

        var context = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        var listItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);
        context.load(listItem);
        context.load(listItem.get_file());
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
                console.log(listItem.get_file().get_checkOutType());
                console.log(SP.CheckOutType.online);
                if(listItem.get_file().get_checkOutType() !== SP.CheckOutType.online) {
                    checkOutItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl, context, listItem);
                }else{
                    //item is checked out
                    updateListItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl, context, listItem);
                }

            }),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );      
    });    

}
function checkOutItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl,context, listItem){   
    listItem.get_file().checkOut();
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log("successfully item is checked out");
        updateListItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl, context, listItem);
    },
    function (sender, args) {
    console.log("failed: " + args.get_message());
    });
}
async function updateListItem(listName, itemId, itemProperties, pageurl,context, listItem) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+itemId+")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {          
            console.log('Success');
            //check in 
            listItem.get_file().checkIn();
            // publish
            listItem.get_file().publish("Publishing");
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    console.log("item is published");
                    window.location.replace(pageurl + "?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design");
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                console.log("failed: " + args.get_message());
                });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "Item";
}  

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**Update**: check out item before redirecting page.

```
Update();
function Update() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        var listName = "Pages";   
        var itemId = 1; // Update Item Id here
        var titleVal = "test";
        var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
        var itemProperties = {
            "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
            "Title": titleVal    
        };
        var pageurl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Sites/<site>/Pages/p1.aspx";

        var context = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        var listItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);
        context.load(listItem);
        context.load(listItem.get_file());
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
                console.log(listItem.get_file().get_checkOutType());
                console.log(SP.CheckOutType.online);
                if(listItem.get_file().get_checkOutType() !== SP.CheckOutType.online) {
                    checkOutItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl, context, listItem);
                }else{
                    //item is checked out
                    updateListItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl, context, listItem);
                }

            }),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );      
    });    

}
function checkOutItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl,context, listItem){   
    listItem.get_file().checkOut();
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log("successfully item is checked out");
        updateListItem(listName,itemId,itemProperties, pageurl, context, listItem);
    },
    function (sender, args) {
    console.log("failed: " + args.get_message());
    });
}
async function updateListItem(listName, itemId, itemProperties, pageurl,context, listItem) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+itemId+")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {          
            console.log('Success');
            //check in 
            listItem.get_file().checkIn();
            // publish
            listItem.get_file().publish("Publishing");
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    console.log("item is published");
                    //redirect page
                    redirectPage(listItem,context,pageurl)
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                console.log("failed: " + args.get_message());
                });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "Item";
}

function redirectPage(listItem,context,pageurl){
    listItem.get_file().checkOut();
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        console.log("successfully item is checked out");
        window.location.replace(pageurl + "?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design");
    },
    function (sender, args) {
    console.log("failed: " + args.get_message());
    });
}  

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: i added only the error handler code but still nothing appears on the console menu.

Comment: test with the code I provided above

Comment: it worked but can you give some more explanation for the code please

Comment: i do get an alert that tell me to check out the page to edit it, doesn't the above code check it out before redirecting?

Comment: You can check out the item before redirecting. check my update.